# Phantom blue lights under white LED headlights?

Tags: optics

Why do I see phantom blue lights just under (and a little to the left) of white LED headlights?  They appear over where the fender is, so just a few inches below the actual lights.  As the vehicle approaches me, they disappear.

Comment: Color aberration, either in your eyes or your glasses?

Comment: Do you have astigmatism?